# Pylint recursive bug when directory is prefix of another directory

Tags: python, pylint

I am observing weird behavior for pylint when I have a directory name being a prefix of another directory. Here is minimal setup to reproduce:

```
mkdir pylint_test
cd pylint_test
mkdir dataset
touch dataset/__init__.py
mkdir dataset_123
echo "from collections import Counter" > dataset_123/a.py
echo "[master]\nenable= all" > pylintrc
pylint --recursive=y .
```

I would expect to get an error for unused import in a.py, but this does not happen. What is more weird - if I remove the file `__init__.py` in dataset (or rename it) I get the output as expected:

```
pylint --recursive=y .
************* Module a
eval_123/a.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
eval_123/a.py:1:0: W0611: Unused Counter imported from collections (unused-import)
```

And what is more weird - if I do not remove `__init__.py` but rename the two directories to be `eval` and `eval_123` respectively again everything works.

Another experiment is renaming dataset_123 to dataset_b123. In that case pylint reports the issues as expected (even when `__init__.py` is present.

I am on Mac Ventura 13.4.1 and here are my package versions:

```
pylint --version
pylint 2.15.2
astroid 2.13.5
Python 3.8.13 (default, Oct 19 2022, 17:52:09)
[Clang 12.0.0 ]
```

However this also reproduces with other python versions.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, and I would recommend raising an issue on the pylint GitHub repository.

I were able to narrow down the [bug to this line](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/3de196c91bcf67e92e5413dea09eb65c4d15c37e/pylint/lint/pylinter.py#L630) which is under [`_discover_files` method](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/3de196c91bcf67e92e5413dea09eb65c4d15c37e/pylint/lint/pylinter.py#L619-L653). This method is responsible for discovering python modules and packages recursively(equivalent to `--recursive=y` option).

```
if any(root.startswith(s) for s in skip_subtrees):
    # Skip subtree of already discovered package.
    continue
```

I believe this check was intended to exclude the subtree(for example `dataset/foo`) if the [search determines that we are already in a package](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/3de196c91bcf67e92e5413dea09eb65c4d15c37e/pylint/lint/pylinter.py#L643-L645)(for example `dataset/__init__.py`). However, it also inadvertently excludes other repositories that `startswith` the same name.

Comment: hm but it is still strange that `eval` works but dataset does not

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I think it's the order in which [`os.walk`](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/3de196c91bcf67e92e5413dea09eb65c4d15c37e/pylint/lint/pylinter.py#L629) iterate in mac.

Comment: I tested locally with doing the os.walk like `for root, _, files in sorted(os.walk(something), reverse=True):` and now pylint reports the issues. so your speculation about the order os.walk yields seems to be correct